# Min - Max Weapon Damage formula in video games

Tags: mathematics, unreal, rpg

I currently working on an RPG game and I'm looking for are formula for creating/generating a min-max weapon damage for an item.

Why in Diablo for example, when a weapon is dropped from an enemy, the weapon damage is 24-72 (just as an example)? it seems that each time the item is dropped those values are randomly generated and changed. So the same weapon could drop twice but his min-max weapon damage could be different.

Is there a math formula that calculates those min-max values when the engine creates the item? what's the legality of that formula? like `ItemLevel` * 2 or something.

I couldn't find on the internet anyone who talks about how those min-max values are generated in video games.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: because the developers made it that way. There's no single rule that all game use to generate randomized ranges. Usually, *how* the randomness is implemented will depend on *why* the developers are adding it. And again, that's going to vary depending on the game & situation.

Some of the reasons designers might add randomness because it:

- is an expected convention of a genre. For example games based on table top RPGs.
- may reduce guaranteed win scenarios and or create the opportunity for upset victories. For example an overpowered attacker might still get low random numbers allowing an underdog defender to survive.
- might be introduced to adjust the skill ceiling. The outcome of static (non-random) events puts a greater emphasis on player skill.
- is considered part of "finding the fun." Some players enjoy pouring over multiple variables of uncertainty to find ideal combinations for their play style.

For additional information on the *why* of randomness I suggest searching through our questions searching for "random" and either the [game-design](/questions/tagged/game-design) or [game-mechanics](/questions/tagged/game-mechanics) tags. I specifically recommend:

- [Does "critical chance" have any reason to exist?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/206341/33287)
- [Are random events beyond players' control necessary for "strategy" games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/206341/33287)

For more information about the math behind these calculations, I suggest:

- [How to develop RPG Damage Formulas?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/14314/33287)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll learning from those links you provided.